# Is there a powershell wildcard for users?

Tags: powershell, admin, local

I need a script to remove local admin users that get created when they set up their devices. I use the command `net localgroup administrators AzureAD\NameOfUser /delete`.

How can I have a wildcard in place of "NameOfUser"? There is only one user in that group that starts with `AzureAD\` so a wild card for any amount of characters would work for me. I tried `AzureAD\*` that doesn't seem to be accepted.

Comment: `net.exe` isn't native to PowerShell, but it is a utility which PowerShell can call. You might want to tag `cmd.exe` and `net.exe`.

Comment: If you want to do this using PowerShell you can use this command `Get-LocalGroupMember administrators | ? {$_.Name -match "^AzureAD\\"} | Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group administrators`

Comment: @Daniel I get the error message "failed to compare two elements in the array"

Comment: Looks like this may be a [known issue with Get-LocalGroupMember](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2996) .  Do you also get the error when only running `Get-LocalGroupMember administrators`?

Comment: @Daniel No. Just running it with your command triggers the error.

Comment: Interesting.  Well I don't think it could possibly be the `Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^AzureAD\\"}` throwing the error so that only leaves the `Remove-LocalGroupMember` part.  Not sure why though

Comment: If it is the Remove-LocalGroupMember throwing the error I guess you can try something like this instead `Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators | Where-Object -Property Name -Like "AzureAD\*" | Foreach-Object { net localgroup administrators $_.Name /DELETE }`

Comment: Or you could avoid both `Get-LocalGroupMember` and `Remove-LocalGroupMember` using something like this `(net localgroup administrators) -like 'AzureAD\*' | ForEach-Object { net localgroup administrators $_ /DELETE }`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments you can probably use

```
(net localgroup administrators) -like 'AzureAD\*' | ForEach-Object { net localgroup administrators $_ /DELETE }
```

Essentially you are taking the response of `net localgroup administrators`, filtering for only lines that start with "AzureAD" using `-like` and then running `net local group administrators <object_name> /DELETE` for each matching object